# PrintOut set to 3 but only produces 1 copy

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am attempting to print 3 copies of this one page report titled "rptMap".

For some reason what I get is one copy of the report, followed by 3 copies of the form "Navigation Form"

The rptMap is viewed through a subform of the Navigation Form

```
Private Sub tabPrintMap_Click()

DoCmd.OpenReport "rptMap"
DoCmd.PrintOut , , , , 3
DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptMap"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me annotate the code you just written:

```
'Open the report in the default view, which means, print it and don't open it at all
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptMap" 
'Print the currently selected object, which is the navigation form, 3 times
DoCmd.PrintOut , , , , 3
'Close the report, however, it was not open, it only got printed
DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptMap"
```

There are a couple of ways you can print the report 3 times, the most simple one is the following:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptMap" 'Print report
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptMap" 'Again
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptMap" 'And again
```

Or, if you want to use `DoCmd.PrintOut`, and have a bit more flexibility:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptMap", acViewPreview 'Open the report in print preview
DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, "rptMap" 'Select it
DoCmd.PrintOut Copies:=3 'Print it 3 times, but now it's readable
DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptMap"
```

Comment: I've gone with the simple solution for now.  When I use the second solution the system comes back with run time error 2004.  I believe the error stems from the fact that the report is essentially 35 sub reports loaded on to one report.  Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `.OpenReport` action **prints** the report selected and then closes it. The action `.PrintOut` then works on the active object, which is now the form (as the report has been closed).

You can either use:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptMap"
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptMap"
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptMap"
```

or else:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptMap",acViewPreview
DoCmd.PrintOut , , , , 3
DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptReport"
```

Regards,